# Converting to geometry_msgs/twist

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have a question about sending velocity commands. I have a tcp interpreter that breaks down a normal tcp string with a regular expression and sends it as a ros string. I want it to publish a command velocity as a geometry_msgs/twist. My problem comes from the message type...

The recieved string is a linear velocity in m/sec and an angular velocity in rad/sec. How does one convert this to a Twist message?

thanks,

-Hunter A.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39772/converting-to-geometry_msgs/twist/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, I would try to avoid using strings because you might run into problems because of number encoding and maybe truncated digits.

To fill the twist message, just set twist.linear.x to your linear velocity and twist.angular.z to your angular velocity.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-25**:
Thanks! The reason for the strings is the lab down the hall... They don't write code for robots and they use windows. I code the interface for the robots, and it uses tcp (just like ros) to communicate. It worked in player, so I just changed it to work in ros.